# ¿Como hacer que mi código Javascript no sea tan legible para el usuario?

Tags: javascript

Estuve revisando códigos en javascript y las formas de que no sea tan legible para el usuario y encontré esta manera:

> ¿Me puede decir que tipo de encriptación es esto?
>
> ¿Como se llama la herramienta para poder hacer que mi código se vuelva así?

```
this.jcA_R4[this.gCe_Hk[0]][1](["RdbyTI/zTb55","YrEoV=i=1jUB1wDqVEEo","T3DoQjDoHk/=1jUr1rjt","1Ejt1rEr1wkrQEyBkFCC","XrEoTrEoCoE=1Ez=14Xr","kFhrgFSrQEyNkJEojJEo","kJEo3oz=13ir1Mz=1IEB","1IUr1rTB18GFi1DoikEo","YYUsiFhDX/DojNDoTnDo","VIEokFEoXnDoT3DoikEo","B=DB1rUr1MDt1jit1j+B","lFh=hFhskFSsjFCsYEhM","XIEoUjDoR/DokFDoQjEo","ioEoksDoqsEr1jjt1nDt","lFCrZESrlFCrZEhEV/Do","WnEoR3DoigD=1jDB1jDr","1jEB1nVBQECsRECrkFSs","jFhCiJEoYU2BjFhtlFCs","SESBhFCMkk/=14j=hFhF","S/DoQrEoj1Doj1DoXJFG","vn/BVECrSEhrhFyrlFyC","X/DoQ/DoG1z=1MzB1nUB","QEC=VECBZECsYEhrWEh=","YECthFhrZEhsioUr1nDt","1wTB1jj=1BDB1M1LTjEo","hFEoTIEo9MV=A11BiFC=","lFhsgFyrgxDoR/DoUrDr","1YEthFy=ZEhORrEoRjEo","YnEoWjEo7rDr1BE=1r1s","hFy=ZESBXEhrgFCtZEC=","kFhrlFCKXjEokgDoY3Do","YBEoXIEoYnDoXnEoigDo","TwDoTjEoDkir1jjt1nzB","1YCsiFyKlkDoWrEo2oUs","1j/B14EskFSsgFCNYwDo","A=E=1nFtgFCB6Mzr1Iz=","1Il=gFSsZEhrQEyrRECr","YEhMWEUs1nDt1EUB13zr","1jWsQECqIgTsiFhtQEy=","gFCtZEyrhFy=REhslFhs","QEysZECNSEEohFDojNDo","R/DogoEoXwDotxzB1Ujr","hFC=TEyNjkDoJkit1rTB","1jD=1/jsY/Doh=Eojsir","1/zB1E/=1rD=1/ir1Bir","1jUFXrjt1BUs1nmrQECC","WBEoagDr14EBhFC=hFyG","ZjDoRnDohsDonxE=jFCL","Y3DoW3zr1Ejr1BzB1Bzr","1/it13z=1nDr1EE=YEht","gFCKj01BkFysREC=QEy=","iFSBhJEoikEoVjDoQjEo","TIEoZjEoSnEojJEo7Rls","ZESrYECsYEhskFSslFC=","REy=TEy=kFSshFCBgFCr","lFyGKRGqZjEoQ/DokxDo","jFEoUjDoCkE=1r/=1Bzr","1nUs1/D=1BEt13Dr1Mzr","13D=1wDt1B/B1jEB1EUs","1jDB1jEr1nj=13z=1jEt","1BDt1B2FkxDo2s/=1MDr","1rUB18C=REhsiFh=YECE","VEEo2Nir1jE=1nDB13i=","1/Dr1wDt1rDt14VrREyr","jFCOjFDov0WBjFyETrEo","QEEoVnDoUnDoR=/B1nEB","1ri=kFyrREy=ZEyshFSB","kFhtSEysZEy=Y3DoTBEo","ZwDoUEEoisDol=EokgDo","ZEEolgDB1BUs1Mz=1Izr","1jD=1ED=1UjNjFEoX/Do","goEoQIEoV/DoQrEohsDo","TEEoXjEojsDoi1DoZEEo","goEoX/DoRBEoR3DoSEEo","k=EoW/DoQNF=YEhsQEh=","hFCrkFSqXjDo2Jjr1BzB","1rEr1EDt14CNWnEogkDo","CFjt1YlNYnDojkEokFDo","hxDoWjDokxDo","Rd/zSIWs"]);
```

> ¿Una vez encriptado se puede volver a un paso anterior?

Usaba esta herramienta, es muy buena ya que no puedes retroceder al código anterior al 100%.

https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Comment: es simple javascript con html solo , o usas webpack, grunt o node?

Comment: Es una extensión para google chrome.

Comment: Aquí te dejo un artículo sobre el tema para enciptar y desencriptar con node

Comment: uglifyJs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653578/how-to-uglify-javascript-using-uglifyjs-2

Comment: Bueno, gracias lo revisaré.

Answer (score 6):

El termino no es "***encriptar***", se llama ofuscar el código o minificarlo y normalmente se hace para reducir el tamaño de los archivos. No solo es recomendado ***minificar*** los ***javascripts*** sino también los archivos ***css*** e incluso el ***html***.

La forma mas común de aplicarlo es usando ***Uglify*** junto a ***Gulp*** o ***Webpack***.

Tienes una carpeta ***src*** donde tienes tus archivos de desarrollo y una carpeta ***dist*** donde estarán los archivos minificados que son generador por ***Gulp***, ***Webpack*** o la herramienta que elijas y desde el ***html*** llamas los archivos de la carpeta ***dist***

Ejemplo:

```
<script src="dist/minificado.js"></script>
```

los archivos que tengas en src serán los que uses para el desarrollo y no se verán alterados

Answer (score 0):

Si el ofuscador de código es muy bueno, entonces hacer el proceso inverso no hará muy legible el código.

Usar una herramienta como la que mencionas está bien si tienes un archivo, o estás haciendo algunas pruebas, pero si realmente quieres ofuscar el código de una aplicación, te recomiendo utilizar alguna herramienta como `grunt` o `gulp`, junto con alguna librería como `uglifyJS`. Esta es la [documentación de Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), en inglés, y este es un muy buen artículo que habla sobre el tema: [link](http://blog.hostdime.com.co/13-herramientas-para-minificar-javascript/)